# Cannot get phpseclib to connect - error 10060

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I cannot get my local environment, Win7 running easyPHP 12, to connect to my server, ubuntu 11.04.

I connect to my server via sftp with filezilla fine, i can connect to my server via ssh with putty fine... the server requires no keys at the moment just a uname and pword...

I don't get it, the details i am passing via the php script are exactly the same as the ones i pass from filezilla and putty.

This is the code stripped to the bare basic:

```
//inlcude the phpseclib path in the include array and include the ssh2 class
set_include_path( WEBROOT_PRIVATE.'scripts/phpseclib0.3.0' );
if(!include('Net/SSH2.php')){
    echo 'Sorry failed to load SSH2 class';
    br();
}
if(!include('Net/SFTP.php')){
    echo 'Sorry failed to load SFTP class';
    br();
}
$connection = new Net_SFTP( 'xx.xx.xx.xx', 'xx' );
echo 'ss';
$login = $connection->login( 'username', 'password');
exit();
```

And this is the response i am getting:

> Notice: Cannot connect to xx.xx.xx.xx. Error 10060. A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond. in
>   ....\www_private\scripts\phpseclib0.3.0\Net\SSH2.php
>   on line 776 ss

Answer (score 0):

Most likely server requires keyboard-interactive auth, while component tries password auth.

Comment: The 'ss' is being output after the error - not before. Since the 'ss' is being echo'd before the login that means the error can't be with the login. Plus, phpseclib will try keyboard-interactive if password authentication fails.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing with fsockopen with the error that you're getting, which suggests to me it's not a phpseclib problem so much as a PHP one.

So the way SSH works is that the server sends a banner immediately to you when you try to connect. It does that for stackoverflow.com for example:

```
<?php
$fsock = fsockopen('www.stackoverflow.com', 22);
echo fgets($fsock, 1024);
```

When I run that script I get "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3" back.

My guess would be that if you update that PHP script to work with your server you'll get the same error message phpseclib is giving you.

Comment: Firstly apologies for the delay. The error i get is not the same... Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx:xx (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ) in D:\Files\mid_branch\www_private\application\tinyMvc.php on line 21

Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\Files\mid_branch\www_private\application\tinyMvc.php on line 22

Comment: Yah - it sounds like it's a PHP problem. That said I'm wondering if this link doesn't apply to you: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/private-key-incorrect-for-solution?replies=2