# PHP FTP/SFTP switch class

Tags: php, design-patterns, ftp, sftp, phpseclib

OK, so accessing other servers from your own via either ftp or sftp... I have written a small class to handle either.. It is obviously new and could easily be improved so thought i would throw it out here and see what other people think (stackoverflow gets a hell of a lot of views so hopefully this could help someone else), and how they can improve on it... so i guess the question is... how can this be improved?

```
class ftp_sftp{
//determine, if ssh, to use phpseclib or php's inbuilt ssh_sftp 'libssh'
public $ssh_type = 'phpseclib';
//set ths path to the directory containing the entire phpseclib files
public $phpseclib_path = 'scripts/phpseclib0.3.0';

//private vars generated by this class
public $host;
public $username;
public $password;
public $connection_type;
public $port_number;
public $connection = false;

//contruct method which will attempt to set the connection details and automatically attempt to establisha connection to the server
public function __construct( $host, $username, $password, $connection_type, $port_number = false ){

    //add the webroot to the beginning of the $this->phpseclib_path (this is bespoke to my own configuration)
    $this->phpseclib_path = WEBROOT_PRIVATE.$this->phpseclib_path;

    //setting the classes vars
    $this->host         = $host;
    $this->username     = $username;
    $this->password     = $password;
    $this->connection_type = $connection_type;

    //set the port number to defaults based on connection type if none passed
    if( $port_number === false ){
        if( $connection_type == 'ftp' ){
            $port_number = 21;
        } else {
            $port_number = 22;
        }
    }
    $this->port_number = $port_number;

    //now set the server connection into this classes connection var
    $this->connection = $this->connect();
}

//tests the details passed and tries to establish a connection, returns false on fail.
function connect(){
    br($this->connection_type);
    switch( $this->connection_type )
        {
            case 'ftp':
                        $connection = ftp_connect($this->host);
                        $login = ftp_login($connection, $this->username, $this->password);

                        //if no connection was possible return false and leave $this-connection as false
                        if(!$connection || !$login){
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            // enabling passive mode
                            ftp_pasv( $connection, true );
                            return $connection;
                        }
            break;

            case 'sftp':
                        //decide which ssh type to use
                        switch( $this->ssh_type ){
                            case 'phpseclib':
                                    //inlcude the phpseclib path in the include array and include the ssh2 class
                                    set_include_path($this->phpseclib_path );
                                    if(!include('Net/SSH2.php')){
                                        echo 'Sorry failed to load SSH2 class';
                                        br();
                                    }
                                    if(!include('Net/SFTP.php')){
                                        echo 'Sorry failed to load SFTP class';
                                        br();
                                    }

                                    $connection = new Net_SFTP($this->host, $this->port_number);
                                    $login = $connection->login($this->username, $this->password);
                            break;

                            case 'libssh2':
                                    $connection = ssh2_connect($this->host, $this->port_number);
                                    $login = ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'secret');
                            break;

                            default:
                                    echo 'No ssh method defined, please define one in: $ftp_sftp->ssh_type';
                                    exit();
                            break;
                        }


                        //if no connection was possible return false and leave $this-connection as false
                        if (!$connection || !$login) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return $connection;
                        }
            break;

            default: echo 'No connection type set cannot choose a method to connect';
            break;
        }
}

//acces the phpseclib errors
public function errors(){
if($this->connection_type == 'sftp' && $this->ssh_type == 'phpseclib'){
        print_r($this->connection->getErrors());
    } else {
        echo 'no error logs available';
    }
}

//function used by this class to check certain values are set
public function connection_check(){
    if( $this->connection === false){
        echo 'Sorry there seems to be a connection problem please try again';
        br();
    }

    if( $this->connection_type === false){
        echo 'Sorry there seems to be a no connection type set';
    }

    if( $this->connection === false || $this->connection_type === false ){
        exit();
    }
}

//transfers a file to the connected server
public function put($targetLocationToSendTo, $existingLocationToSendFrom){

    //check the connection
    $this->connection_check();

    switch( $this->connection_type )
        {
            case 'ftp':
                        //ftp_put the file across
                        $put = ftp_put( $this->connection, $targetLocationToSendTo, $existingLocationToSendFrom, FTP_BINARY);
            break;

            case 'sftp':
                        //decide which ssh type to use
                        switch( $this->ssh_type ){
                            case 'phpseclib':
                                    $put = $this->connection->put( $targetLocationToSendTo, $existingLocationToSendFrom, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE );
                            break;

                            case 'libssh2':
                                    $put = ssh2_scp_send($this->connection, $targetLocationToSendTo, $existingLocationToSendFrom, 0755);
                            break;
                        }
            break;
        }

    return $put;
}

//list the contents of a remote directory
public function dir_list( $dirToList ){

    //check the connection
    $this->connection_check();

    //run appropriate list
    switch( $this->connection_type )
        {
            case 'ftp':
                        $list = $this->connection = ftp_nlist($this->connection, $dirToList);
            break;

            case 'sftp':
                        //decide which ssh type to use
                        switch( $this->ssh_type ){
                            case 'phpseclib':
                                    $list = $this->connection->nlist( $dirToList );
                            break;

                            case 'libssh2':
                                    echo 'Sorry there is no support for nlist with libssh2, however this link has a possible answer: http://randomdrake.com/2012/02/08/listing-and-downloading-files-over-sftp-with-php-and-ssh2/';
                            break;
                        }
            break;
        }

    return $list;
}

//get the timestamp of the file on another server
public function remote_filemtime( $pathToFile ){

    //check the connection
    $this->connection_check();

    //run appropriate list
    switch( $this->connection_type )
        {
            case 'ftp':
                        $timeStamp = ftp_mdtm($this->connection, $pathToFile);
            break;

            case 'sftp':
                        //decide which ssh type to use
                        switch( $this->ssh_type ){
                            case 'phpseclib':
                                    $statinfo = $this->connection->stat( $pathToFile );
                            break;

                            case 'libssh2':
                                    $statinfo = ssh2_sftp_stat($this->connection, $pathToFile);
                            break;
                        }

                        if($statinfo['mtime']){
                            $timeStamp = $statinfo['mtime'];
                        } else {
                            $timeStamp = false;
                        }
            break;
        }

    return $timeStamp;
}

//make a directory on the remote server
public function make_dir( $dirToMake ){
    //check the connection
    $this->connection_check();

    //run appropriate list
    switch( $this->connection_type )
        {
            case 'ftp':
                        $dir_made = ftp_mkdir($this->connection, $dirToMake);
            break;

            case 'sftp':
                        //decide which ssh type to use
                        switch( $this->ssh_type ){
                            case 'phpseclib':
                                    $statinfo = $this->connection->mkdir( $dirToMake );
                            break;

                            case 'libssh2':
                                    $statinfo = ssh2_sftp_mkdir($this->connection, $dirToMake, 0755);
                            break;
                        }
            break;
        }

    return $dir_made;
}

//change directory
public function change_dir( $dirToMoveTo ){
    //check the connection
    $this->connection_check();

    //run appropriate list
    switch( $this->connection_type )
        {
            case 'ftp': $chdir = ftp_chdir($this->connection, $dirToMoveTo );
            break;

            case 'sftp':
                        //decide which ssh type to use
                        switch( $this->ssh_type ){
                            case 'phpseclib':
                                    $chdir = $this->connection->chdir( $dirToMoveTo );
                            break;

                            case 'libssh2':
                                    echo 'Sorry this feature does exist yet for when using libssh2 with the ftp_sftp class';
                                    exit();
                            break;
                        }
            break;
        }

    return $chdir;
}

//curent directory we are looking in
public function pwd(){

    //check the connection
    $this->connection_check();

    //run appropriate list
    switch( $this->connection_type )
        {
            case 'ftp': $pwd = ftp_pwd($this->connection);
            break;

            case 'sftp':
                        //decide which ssh type to use
                        switch( $this->ssh_type ){
                            case 'phpseclib':
                                    $pwd = $this->connection->pwd();
                            break;

                            case 'libssh2':
                                    echo 'Sorry this feature does exist yet for when using libssh2';
                                    exit();
                            break;
                        }
            break;
        }

    return $pwd;
}

//delete file
public function delete_file($fileToDelete){
    //check the connection
    $this->connection_check();

    //run appropriate list
    switch( $this->connection_type )
        {
            case 'ftp': $unlink = ftp_delete($this->connection, $fileToDelete);
            break;

            case 'sftp':
                        //decide which ssh type to use
                        switch( $this->ssh_type ){
                            case 'phpseclib':
                                    $unlink = $this->connection->delete( $fileToDelete );
                            break;

                            case 'libssh2':
                                    $unlink = ssh2_sftp_unlink($this->connection, $fileToDelete);
                            break;
                        }
            break;
        }

    return $unlink;
}   }//end of class
```

Using the class:

```
$ftp_sftp = new ftp_sftp( '92.21.627.163', 'ftpuser', 'yourpassword', '', 'ftp', '21' );
echo $ftp_sftp->pwd();
```

I am having a little trouble getting the phpseclib to connect on my win7 machine using easyPHP and have started a Q.. if anyone has any ideas i would be very grateful...
[Cannot get phpseclib to connect - error 10060](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326406/cannot-get-phpseclib-to-connect-error-10060)

Comment: I'd recommend inheritance to cut down on those switch statements.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: I went all out on the answer, because this is such a common issue out there in the wild.  Hopefully it makes sense.  If you master Strategy Pattern, one of the simplest design patterns, I assure you you'll instantly bypass 75% of the developers around you in skill!  If you get hooked on patterns pick up the standard pack, and you'll be a ninja.

Comment: FYI though, sounds like you're asking two questions here, 1. how to improve the code, 2. why the win7/easyPHP problem.  I've answered 1., sounds like @neubert has answered 2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The main *problem* with this code is it *scales vertically*.  Suppose you decide to add another implementation, a local filesystem, introducing a third potential value for `$connection_type` of *'file'* say.  Now you have to go through the code adding `case 'file':` conditions everywhere, making `ftp_sftp` grow out of control.  You've got the same problem again inside of the 'sftp' branch of code right now, dealing with `$ssh_type`.

**Original code**

```
switch($connection_type) {
    case 'ftp'  : // ...
    case 'stfp' : // ...
}
```

**Becomes**

```
switch($connection_type) {
    case 'ftp'  : // ...
    case 'stfp' : // ...
    case 'file' : // ...
}
```

Bear in mind this is for **every switch statement** in the code that switches on `$connection_type`.  Imagine how many lines of code we'd add to the `ftp_sftp` class to incorporate each additional behavior...

In fact, it looks like you actually have 3 strategies right now, *ftp*, *sftp* & *ssh*.

What you want to do here is set the code up to expand *horizontally* rather than *vertically* and the way to do that is via the [Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Essentially what you're doing is pulling out the common interface in your code, then creating separate implementations for FTP & SFTP.  There are lots of different ways to go on the actual implementation on this, so tweak to your heart's content!

**A common interface**

This is the definition of what any 'ftp class' must be able to do.

```
interface PhpFtp
{
    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $port_number = false);
    public function connect();
    public function errors();
    public function connection_check();
    public function put($targetLocationToSendTo, $existingLocationToSendFrom);
    public function dir_list( $dirToList );
    public function remote_filemtime( $pathToFile );
    public function make_dir( $dirToMake );
    public function change_dir( $dirToMoveTo );
    public function pwd();
    public function delete_file($fileToDelete);
}
```

**A factory**

Now there is a single switch statement throughout the code that checks `$connection_type`.  You might decide to handle the `default` case differently.

```
class PhpFtpFactory
{
    public static function create($connection_type)
    {
        switch($connection_type) {
            case 'ftp':
                $oFtp = new Ftp();
                break;
            case 'sftp':
                $oFtp = new Sftp();
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnexpectedValueExcpetion(
                    'No connection type set cannot choose a method to connect');
        }

        // Potential follow-up construction steps
        return $oFtp;
    }
}
```

**A base class**

Not strictly necessary, but very helpful.  Also, we're sneaking in another design pattern here, called [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).  `BaseFtp::pwd` is a template method, it controls the overall *pwd* algorithm, but delegates to concrete children for a portion of it.

```
abstract class BaseFtp implements PhpFtp
{
    public function pwd()
    {
        $this->connection_check();
        return $this->_pwd();
    }

    abstract protected function _pwd();
}
```

**Concrete FTP implementation**

Now we have a succinct FTP class that only does FTP operations, it knows nothing about SFTP.

```
class Ftp extends BaseFtp
{
    protected function _pwd()
    {
        return ftp_pwd($this->connection);
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $connection = ftp_connect($this->host);
        $login      = ftp_login($connection, $this->username, $this->password);

        // if no connection was possible return false and leave $this-connection as false
        if(!$connection || !$login)
            return false;

        // enabling passive mode
        ftp_pasv( $connection, true );
        return $connection;
    }
}
```

**Concrete SFTP class**

Now we have a standalone SFTP class, however notice it switches on `$ssh_type` just as the original `ftp_sftp` class did for `$connection_type`.  Once you get a handle on Strategy Pattern, and have the `Ftp` & `Sftp` classes finished, you can go back in and implement Strategy Pattern within the `Sftp` implementation so that you have 2 classes `Phpseclib` & `Libssh2`, for instance.

```
class Sftp extends BaseFtp
{
    protected function _pwd()
    {
        // decide which ssh type to use
        switch($this->ssh_type) {
            case 'phpseclib':
                return $this->connection->pwd();

            case 'libssh2':
                echo 'Sorry this feature does exist yet for when using libssh2';
                return false;
        }
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        // decide which ssh type to use
        switch( $this->ssh_type ) {
            case 'phpseclib':
                // inlcude the phpseclib path in the include array
                // and include the ssh2 class
                set_include_path($this->phpseclib_path );
                if(!include('Net/SSH2.php')){
                    echo 'Sorry failed to load SSH2 class';
                    br();
                }
                if(!include('Net/SFTP.php')){
                    echo 'Sorry failed to load SFTP class';
                    br();
                }

                $connection = new Net_SFTP($this->host, $this->port_number);
                $login = $connection->login($this->username, $this->password);
                break;

            case 'libssh2':
                $connection = ssh2_connect($this->host, $this->port_number);
                $login = ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'secret');
                break;

            default:
                echo 'No ssh method defined, please define one in: $ftp_sftp->ssh_type';
                exit();
                break;
        }

        if(!$connection || !$login)
            return false;
    }
}
```

**Putting the new code to use**

With the new system in place its 10X easier to see what's what, each class focuses on it's specific domain and the code grows *horizontally*.  What does that mean?  Remember above, when we considered adding a third `$connection_type` *'file'* in the original paradigm?  In the new arrangement we update **one** switch statement, the one in the factory:

```
class PhpFtpFactory
{
    public static function create($connection_type)
    {
        switch($connection_type) {
            case 'ftp':
                $oFtp = new Ftp();
                break;
            case 'sftp':
                $oFtp = new Sftp();
                break;
            case 'file':
                $oFtp = new File();
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnexpectedValueExcpetion(
                    'No connection type set cannot choose a method to connect');
        }

        // Potential follow-up construction steps
        return $oFtp;
    }
}
```

And then of course you add the new concrete implementation

```
class File extends PhpFtp
{
    // ...
}
```

Since the new `File` class can go in it's own space, we're not expanding one central class, namely the original `ftp_sftp` class.

In order to use the new system, you hit up the factory for an instance and go from there

```
// get an instance of the Ftp class
$ftp  = PhpFtpFactory::create('ftp');

// get an instance of the Sftp class 
$sftp = PhpFtpFactory::create('sftp');
```

Either of these instances support all the `PhpFtp` functions because they implement the interface!  This also gives you the ability to write *polymorphic* code as well.  Consider a function that type-hints against the interface

```
// This is polymorphic code
function doFtpStuff(PhpFtp $oFtp) {
   // As mentioned above $oFtp can be an instance of any class that implements PhpFtp
   $oFtp->connect();
   $oFtp->pwd();
}
```

Comment: Wow.  Thank you very much for the help there.  I can't attempt to implement this until Friday but will let you know how I get along

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress's SFTP implementation does chdir and pwd in a weird way. They do ssh2_exec(). Don't know if that works with file downloading / uploading there. Here's their implementation:

http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ssh2.php

I think phpseclib is better but just fyi.

Also, the latest version of phpseclib is 0.3.1. idk...  just another fyi lol.

Finally, maybe do include_once() instead of include()? That way the class could be instantiated multiple times?